# How would you write the word /ˈtɪə.rɒn/?

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, books

I'm writing a book and made a word called /ˈtɪə.rɒn/ (reading it like TEARdrop + iRON, or something like TEARON). The story is supposed to be medieval fantasy and I'm not a native speaker so I'm not sure how to write the word in a 'cool' way. At first, I thought of 'Tyron' but a friend of mine told me it sounds like the name 'Tyrone' (like TIRE + ON). So I want to know from you guys how to write /ˈtɪə.rɒn/ in a cool way. Do I just write it like 'Tyron' or maybe 'Tiron'? Or is 'Tearon' the best outcome? Or do I just ignore common sense and English grammar and goes with whatever I want, as this is a made up word for a fantasy book?

Comment: Given the popularity of Game of Thrones, I'd avoid anything that sounded (or looked) like "Tyrion" in a new medieval fantasy story.

Comment: I agree with your friend that 'Tyron' would be thought of as the name Tyrone. And yes, the only best outcome is 'Tearon', IMO. *Tear on* was what came to mind when I saw the title of your post.

Comment: "Tearon" would be good, except that many people would read it as "tear-on".  Perhaps "teeron"?

Comment: Really, what you should do is start with a language that is native to your world and go from there. Construct the language first and then words will not pose a problem.

Comment: @HotLicks My problem with "Tearon" is that I almost read it as "tearoom" and I don't believe that I will be alone!

Comment: @KillingTime good reminder.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul yeah... Maybe I'll rethink this name.

Comment: @FeliniusRex thanks for the advice. I'm researching lots of cultures like Norse, Dane, Zulu, among others, to help me come up with words that work. I'm gonna think about the language. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Tiaron" is entirely plausible too, along with "Tyrinn" and "Tirynn"
"Tirohn" too...
Anyways, just a few suggestions.

Comment: oops i just realised that this is an answer and not a comment oh my god

Comment: As a new contributor you don't yet have the permission to post a comment. Keep going, you'll soon hit the threshold.

Comment: I like your suggestions, especially Tyrinn. I'm gonna give it a thought. Also, I made new words for stuff like the mythology within the story's universe. Getting some inspiration from Christian, Arabic, Norse, Dane, Finnish, and some African cultures. Thanks a lot.